# Within a block, what is the practical difference between a __block variable and a static variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I want to reuse an object reference across multiple calls of a single block, and I'm curious: What is the practical difference between the following two approaches?

**Using a `__block` variable:**

```
__block Widget *widget = [self buildNewWidget];

for(Gadget *gadget in self.gadgets) {
    [self useGadget:gadget withCallback:^{
        if([widget isBroken]) {
            widget = [self buildNewWidget];
        }

        gadget.widget = widget;
    }];
}
```

**Using a `static` variable:**

```
for(Gadget *gadget in self.gadgets) {
    [self useGadget:gadget withCallback:^{
        static Widget *widget;

        if(!widget || [widget isBroken]) {
            widget = [self buildNewWidget];
        }

        gadget.widget = widget;
    }];
}
```

Obviously these two chunks of code differ from a semantic perspective, but (practically speaking) I believe they do the same basic work. My guess is that there is a difference from a memory management perspective, a performance perspective, or something else. Any insights that illustrate these differences (or explain why they are not different) would be helpful.

Comment: Can't type a full answer right now, but these behave differently if you put them inside a function that will be called more than once (the former creates a new widget every time, the latter does not).

Comment: @jtbandes I don't think that's true; I would love to see more explanation of what you mean. Based on experimentation, both of these implementations effectively "remember" the last widget that was built and hold onto the reference until the next block is called. Am I missing something?

Comment: The next block, yes — but the enclosing scope matters too. The `__block Widget *` variable is locally scoped, but the `static Widget *` is global to the file (even though it's not visible outside the block).

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you mean now. That's the direction that Ramy was taking with his answer too. You're completely right - if these were two implementations of a method that could be called multiple times the behavior is very different. Good point.

Comment: Your code appears to assume ARC; it's worth making this explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, assume that both examples are wrapped in `-(void)useGadgetsOnWidgets { ... }`.

Assuming ARC, that your app is single-threaded and the code is non-reentrant (i.e. `useGadgetsOnWidgets` does not call itself), and that the block is not used after the method returns, there is one main difference:

With a `static` variable, `widget` sticks around forever. This means widgets get reused across calls to `-useGadgetsOnWidgets` (which can be good and bad), but also means that the Widget gets retained forever. You can change this by pulling the widget out of the loop/Block (I've also inited it at the start to more closely resemble the `__block` version:

```
-(void)useGadgetsOnWidgets {
  static Widget *widget;
  widget = [self buildNewWidget];
  for(Gadget *gadget in self.gadgets) {
    [self useGadget:gadget withCallback:^{
      if([widget isBroken]) {
        widget = [self buildNewWidget];
      }
      gadget.widget = widget;
    }];
  }
  widget = nil;
}
```

There is a third variant which is somewhat thread-safe and assumes that the block is not used after the method returns:

```
-(void)useGadgetsOnWidgets {
  Widget *widget = [self buildNewWidget];
  Widget ** pWidget = &widget;
  for(Gadget *gadget in self.gadgets) {
    [self useGadget:gadget withCallback:^{
      if([*pWidget  isBroken]) {
        *pWidget = [self buildNewWidget];
      }
      gadget.widget = *pWidget ;
    }];
  }
}
```

This seems slightly nicer than using a `static` variable (which is effectively just a global variable), but it's still pretty icky. Neither are techniques I'd want to teach to a novice programmer (but then again, neither is any sort of multithreading).

**EDIT:** For the problem you describe, a better solution than any of these is to just cache the widget in an ivar/property on `self`:

```
-(Widget*)workingWidget {
  // Assuming _cachedWidget is an ivar
  if ([_cachedWidget isBroken]) {
    _cachedWidget = [self buildWidget];
  }
  return _cachedWidget;
}

-(void)useGadgetsOnWidgets {
  for(Gadget *gadget in self.gadgets) {
    [self useGadget:gadget withCallback:^{
      gadget.widget = [self workingWidget];
    }];
  }
}
```

Comment: You got to a weird place with that "third variant" of useGadgetsOnWidgets, but I _love_ your last refactor, after the EDIT using [self workingWidget]... feels like a very "Cocoa" way to solve this problem.

Comment: "With a static variable, widget sticks around forever." - Does that mean it occupies a fundamentally different memory space than a variable reused with __block? Do you know if there are any performance implications associated with this difference?

Comment: Yes. `static` makes it effectively a global variable, `__block` causes it to be wrapped in a way that it can be copied to the heap. (The `Widget` itself is no different, of course; it's just the location of the variable that's different.) `static` should be *slightly* faster due to the wrapping - code that accesses a `__block` variable needs to work whether or not the variable's been copied to the heap, so it goes through an extra layer of indirection. I haven't done any benchmarks, but it's likely to be insignificant (on the order of a method call).

Answer (score 2):

An example is worth a thousand words:

(And yes, this is a very simplistic example, but it is mostly equivalent to what you were doing...)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    // Your example encompasses this scope,
    // not taking into account that we may execute this code multiple times:

    // Call the block
    (^{
        // Every instance/execution of this block will have the same object.
        static Obj *o;

        // Initialize static object
        static dispatch_once_t once;
        dispatch_once(&once, ^{
            o = [Obj new];
        });

        NSLog(@"Object is: %@", o);
    })();
}
// Output:
//   Object is: <Obj: 0x100109fd0>
//   Object is: <Obj: 0x100109fd0>
//   Object is: <Obj: 0x100109fd0>

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    __block Obj *o = [Obj new];

    // Call the block
    (^{
        // This block uses the object from its enclosing scope, which may be different.
        NSLog(@"Object is: %@", o);
    })();
}
// Output:
//   Object is: <Obj: 0x105100420>
//   Object is: <Obj: 0x1003004f0>
//   Object is: <Obj: 0x105300000>
```

Answer (score 1):

As written, these two code fragments work differently and they have different end results.

The second set of code is a failure waiting to happen. It will fail if this code is run on two different threads at the same time due to the use of the static variable. This code is also going to fail because you never initialize the static variable. The first time the `if` statement is reached, the app could crash.

Since each iteration of the loop appears to depend on the current value of `widget`, you need have a local variable that is initialized before the loop. Since this variable needs to be modified inside a block, you need to make the variable a `__block` variable. This means your first set of code is the proper code.

Comment: I honestly don't recall if static are set to nil or not. I never rely on such things. It's trivial and clearer to explicitly initialize the variable. Even if the variable is initialized, it's still fragile code that isn't thread-safe.

Comment: Because if it's initialised to nil it would make it unsafe only with multithreading. Instead if he calls it the first time, since !widget is true it will get allocated.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri If the static is not explicitly initialize to `nil`, then the 2nd use of this code will begin with the last value of the previous use of the code. It's very unlikely that is desired.

Comment: He may wants to use the same widget all times, unless it's broken.

Comment: To keep this conversation focused on track, let's _assume_ that I can guarantee (like via a mutex or other implementation detail) that these blocks will never execute concurrently. The static pointer is implicitly initialized to nil. Whichever block is executed first would be the first to call "buildNewWidget", which is perfectly acceptable for my implementation.

Comment: This case it's perfectly safe.

Comment: @rmaddy The behavior that you're talking about where the 2nd use of this code will begin with the last value of the previous use of code is _exactly_ what is desired for these use cases. If you read my implementation again, I am holding a reference to a sort of "last working widget" which can change after any call to the method. I want to hold onto the last one that I built because building widgets is computationally expensive.

Answer (score -1):

__block makes the variable available inside the block, like if it's global. If you use it inside the block, instead of being copied it will be referenced and since it's like global it will be still alive.But the next time you call that block of code, another variable will be pushed in the stack.

static makes the variable visible only in the scope, and it survives the entire execution of the program. But if you call that block of code another time, the variable will be the same.

Comment: The `static`, like other variables, is only visible inside the curly braces in which it is defined. In this case, the `static` is only visible inside the callback block. Maybe that is what you meant by "function".

Comment: I don't think that's quite correct - any variable in scope can be used  within the block, but without the `__block` a copy is made of that variable and so changes to it inside the block aren't reflected outside of the block.

Comment: There is definitely a big difference when you consider what happens when calling these two chunks of code multiple times, like if these were two different implementations of a method that could be called again and again. Thank you for illustrating this fundamental difference, which is important to understand.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Without the `__block` keyword, it's an error to try to modify the variable inside the block. No copy is made.

Comment: @rmaddy you're right, thanks for the correction! Still, you don't need `__block` to reference a variable within the block's scope, although it looks like the answer has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Correct. You only need __block if you wish to modify the value of the variable inside the block, not to read the variable.

Comment: I thought this way the answer was correct. Does someone see a mistake?